# shell script to compare two files and execute command on remote

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting. I need to write a shell script satisfying the below condition. Let say I have a file hosts.txt

[Dev]
10.10.1.15
10.10.2.15

[QA]
10.20.1.15

and another file properties with below content

order 2.10
cart 2.15.4

I need to write a shell script like ./script.sh DEV properties and it has to start executing in all the servers in DEV env.

Answer (score 0):

For the downstream project you can pick a Pipeline job and use the following script:

```
node {
    stage('do the thing') {
        sh "./my-script.sh"
    }
}
```